# Object.hasOwnProperty multiple levels without error

Tags: javascript, hasownproperty

I wonder if there is some way to use hasOwnProperty for an object for multiple levels.

To illustrate:
I have following object:

```
var Client = {
    ID: 1,
    Details: {
        Title: 'Dr',
        Sex: 'male'
    }
}
```

I can now do the following in javascript:

```
('Title' in Client.Details) -> true
```

However I cannot! do:

```
('Street' in Client.Adress)
```

...yet I must first use an if to not throw an error. Because I might have a large object - I only need to know if there is "Adress" in Client.Details without using prior if statements, any idea if that is possible?

```
// this is overkill -> (will be many more if-statements for checking a lower level
if('Adress' in Client){
    console.log('Street' in Client.Adress)
} else {
    console.log(false)
}
```

Example which produces the error:

```js
var Client = {
    ID: 1,
    Details: {
        Title: 'Dr',
        Sex: 'male'
    }
}

// Results in Error:
('Street' in Client.Adress)

// Results in Error:
if('Street' in Client.Adress){}
```

Comment: `console.log('Adress' in Client && 'Street' in Client.Adress)`?

Comment: I have added an example for you that shows there is an error

Comment: Yes I see that there's an error. But no, it's not overkill to check for every property that you are accessing, and no you don't need many more `if` statements for that.

Comment: Well above is a very simplified example. Imaging an object with 10+ levels and I merely want to know if at level 7 there is object "XYZ" present or not. That would mean 6 (I think) if-statements just to not have the code crash in an error, which in my opinion is overkill

Comment: No, not `if` statements! Just chain them together using the `&&` operator. You can put that expression in a *single* `if` condition. For alternative approaches see the duplicates

Comment: I have updated the sniped for you, the if also runs into an error

Comment: That's not the expression I suggested in my first comment

Comment: Correct, yet your answer did not help my original problem in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the path of your attributes via a `String` and use a recursive function to run your object down:

```
const checkPath = (o, path) => {
  if(path.includes('.')){
    if(o.hasOwnProperty(path.split('.')[0])) return checkPath(o[path.split('.')[0]], path.split('.').slice(1).join('.'));
    else return false
  }else return o.hasOwnProperty(path);
}
```

And use it like this :

```
checkPath(Client, 'Details.Title')
```

***Demo:***

```js
let Client = {
    ID: 1,
    Details: {
        Title: 'Dr',
        Sex: 'male'
    }
};

const checkPath = (o, path) => {
  if(path.includes('.')){
    if(o.hasOwnProperty(path.split('.')[0])) return checkPath(o[path.split('.')[0]], path.split('.').slice(1).join('.'));
    else return false
  }else return o.hasOwnProperty(path);
}

console.log(checkPath(Client, 'Details.Title'));
console.log(checkPath(Client, 'Test.Title'));
```

---

**Here's the sexy one-liner:**

```
const checkPath = (o, path) => path.includes('.') ? o.hasOwnProperty(path.split('.')[0]) ? checkPath(o[path.split('.')[0]], path.split('.').slice(1).join('.')) : false : o.hasOwnProperty(path);
```

Comment: Seems good. Tried with checkPath(Client, 'Details.Address.Drive') and it works. Do you think there is any problems when the object gets more complicated? (containing functions etc.)

Comment: @DavidDunham It won't execute functions for you, if that's what you mean. Other than that, it should hold fine.

Comment: No I meant if the object complexity (with functions) might break the functionality of your code because it's not "common" to have functions in an object.

Comment: As I said, if you check for a path that contains a function, it won't execute it, thus will not continue to check the next attribute.